Got a constructed (sum of items) ordinal IV for a Factorial ANCOVA , how to treat covariates?
I will measure an independent variable (IV) using a 5-point Likert scale on 5 attitude objects. Now, I want to create an IV where the levels represent the occurrences where the participant has a score of at least 4 for each item. Consequently, I would obtain a new IV with 5 levels (representing the number of attitudes scored >=4: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), which is quantitatively ordinal.
Additionally, I have two other items, A and B, measured on the same 5 attitudes, which I need to consider as covariates.
I am contemplating aggregating each covariate by mapping the level of each participant. For instance, if a participant falls into group 2 (indicating 2 scores >=4 on the IV related to the attitude object), I would aggregate the covariate measured on those 2 attitude objects and then compute the mean. Consequently, for each level of the new IV, I would have both the corresponding covariates mapped onto it.
Does this approach sound appropriate?
Moreover, I need also to measure interaction effects. The design would be then 5 (ordinal) X 4 (ordinal) with 2 covariates.
I was thinking about using ANCOVA, but my advisor says that maybe a regression could do the job.
I'm not concerned about assumptions and some other problems (unequal cell size, multicollinearity, homogeneity of regression for each cell), but I'm way concerned about the soundness of it all.
What do you think? What adjustments shall I make? What shall I be aware of?
